# python urllib2. Cannot get data from same IP address of My Server

Tags: java, python, urllib2, flask-restful

Here is my code I'm using in python flask to get data from my own server IP.

```
url = 'http://aa.bb.ccc.ddd:8082/v2/check?'
values = {'language': language,
          'text': text
          }
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
output = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

Details: I have a Java service running on my server on port 8081 which accepts parameter with GET and send some response, here is the URL 
    http://aa.bb.ccc.ddd:8081/v2/check?language=en-US&text=my+text
If I send a request to this in the browser it sends me the response in JSON smoothly.

Now based on this result I have to perform some actions in python and send back to the client when they request from my flask service.

For this I have a service in flask python running on port 8084, the URL is 
http://aa.bb.ccc.ddd:8084/api/askFromAPI

What I want is that when some client sends me to request on flask web service, based on parameters I can request to my own server URL of java service http://aa.bb.ccc.ddd:8081/v2/check?language=en-US&text=my+text, get a response, prepare results from that and send back to the client, but it always timeout.

Client-> FlaskAPI:8084 -> Req. to Java:8081 -> Response to Flask:8084 -> Value Add in Response -> Return to Client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after 2 days to hard work I finally contacted my server provider, and he told me that they have blocked the ports on which I was trying to connect, so after port enabling my script successfully fetched the data from the service.